# Interval "Widths"

Tags: functions

### If $h(x)$ is a function whose domain is $[-8,8]$, and $g(x)=h\left(\frac x2\right)$, then the domain of $g(x)$ is an interval of what width?

Hello, I recently found myself stuck with this problem. Would the first step to be to find a function $h(x)$ with domain $[-8,8]$, then find the domain of $h(\frac{x}2)$, or is there an easier method without finding $h(x)$ itself?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is equivalent to $h$ with the input halved.

What restrictions does the input of $h$ have? Now halve those.

What width does the interval created now have?

Comment: Would that be $8$? That makes sense to me right now, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, $[\frac{-8}{2}, \frac{8}{2}]=[-4,4]$. Try making it something interesting, such as a simple linear equation, or a square or cube (root) of $x$ and see what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

We know that domain of $h(x)$ is $[-8, 8]$

$g(x)$ will have $x$ in its domain if and only if $\frac{x}{2}$ is in the domain of $h(x)$.

i.e. $-8 \le \frac{x}{2} \le 8$

One such possible $x$ is $x = -16$, because $-\frac{16}{2} = -8$ and $-8 \le -8 \le 8$

Domain of $g(x)$ is $[-16, 16]$

Width is $16-(-16) = 32$